# Decrease width of horizontal line only at right part of the site

Tags: html, css

Please visit this [Link](http://demo2.kidsdial.com/)

Below slideshow images, you can see: "TOP OFFERS" text

We inserted "TOP OFFERS" text between 2 horizontal lines, but the line at right is extended more, i want to decrease the width of line at right.

Could you help me to find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this:

```
.horizontal_line span:after {
  right: 3.5%;
  left: auto;
  width: 32%;
}
```

Comment: it did't worked, i want to keep left side line, but i want to decrease width of right side line.....

Comment: Don't change .horizontal_line span:before. Instead of .horizontal_line span:after {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
} add code above

Comment: Please don't change this code .horizontal_line span:before,
.horizontal_line span:after {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    content: " ";
    width: 36%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
 
}

Comment: You can delete .horizontal_line span:after {
   right: 0;  
   left: auto; 
  
} and add code in answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for both of you , both solutions worked , this site is not responsive , please help me here :


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764959/magento-site-is-not-looking-responsive-in-home-page

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code
I have decreased the width of div

```
.horizontal_line div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 1120px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i followed your solution, but left line is completely disappering, what i need is that 

"i want to decrease the line width only in right side"

Comment: Website will not be responsive if you add: width: 1120px;

Comment: thanks a lot for both of you , both solutions worked , this site is not responsive , please help me here :


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764959/magento-site-is-not-looking-responsive-in-home-page